# Python Selenium: Inconsistent webpage loading times with button presses?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am using selenium to create a website shopper to test my python skills. I have managed to get most of it working except for some inconsistencies in page loading times which I cannot fix but I think I know why it is happening.

When i load the item page on the shop I use the following code:

```
  try:
        cartbttn = driver.find_element_by_name('commit')
        if cartbttn.is_displayed():
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('commit')[0].click()")
            print("Added to cart")
    except(StaleElementReferenceException):
        return(115)
```

The code usually runs fine and the script completes it's runtime in 2.5 seconds on average.
The issue is that occasionally pressing either the 'add cart' button or the 'checkout' button lags out the page and causes the page to 'pause' for a few seconds as if it is processing and then the action is completed. I know this isn't latency on their side as the site is not busy and when I do this manually pressing the buttons there is never an issue.

I believe that what should happen is that the button press javascript is executed when the button is fully 'visible' and clickable but occasionally the button press is called before this and causes the site to glitch and require this catch up time.

I have tried waiting for the element to be visible and using the element.click() function which gives no effect. I thought using JavaScript to call the button press would work but this did not either.

I also added manual sleeps which helped. The only issue with the sleeps is that they have to be big enough for worst case scenarios which means you lose the speed advantage of times the site runs quicker.

The expected result is for the button to be pressed and wait until the 'checkout' button appears before trying to press the checkout button so no issues with the site arise.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to invoke `click()` on the element instead of using `is_displayed()` or *waiting for the element to be visible* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "commit"))).click()
    print("Added to cart")
except(TimeoutException):
    return("Error while adding to cart")
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```